# How do I describe and calculate the effect of an impacting object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, collision

My lab studies the physiology of impact injury on biological tissues. I use a pneumatic cylinder to impart injury into a biological sample and then assess the molecular and physiological changes in that tissue. It is the first step in trying to understand the pathophysiology of traumatic brain injury. So, I have the mass of the internal moving components of the cylinder (the rod and piston body = 25grams) and I have the velocity of these moving components (let's call it 10m/s). I also have the sample and cylinder set up so that the total displacement is 5mm. The sample sits on a foam pad. Some of this displacement is represented by compression of the sample, but for the most part the sample rapidly accelerates and decelerates through this 5mm displacement.

Most of the related literature simply reports the velocity of the impact. However, I know enough physics to know that velocity is but one piece of the impact physics. So, my questions:

1. Colloquially, one might ask what is the force imparted on the tissue. But, that might not be the correct term. What is the best way to label the effect of the cylinder on the tissue? Is Force correct? Would it be Kinetic Energy? I'm just trying to figure out the most informative/accurate description of the effect of the cylinder on the tissue.
2. Then, how do I calculate that (what ever it is: force, KE, ...)?

Comment: I think in forensics it is common to use kinetic energy when talking about trauma. $K_e=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ I would think this type of tissue vs damage would have common tests and criteria for characterization already as surface area, tissue type, velocity and mass all play a role in simulating whatever event you are trying to duplicate.

Comment: Energy deposited per unit volume or energy deposited per unit mass is probably the right way to think about it. Note that energy density (J/m$^3$) and pressure (N/m$^2$) have the same units.

Comment: http://books.google.com.lb/books/about/Impact.html?id=qzSmhW2hkFQC&redir_esc=y

Comment: Peak strain of tissue would be the ultimate goal in describing the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the mechanical damage just after impact that is of interest, and not the recovery, you are interested in what is felt locally at the scale of a single cell e.g.

Then the quantities you may want to calculate are also local: e.g., the energy dissipated in the tissue per unit volume. The energy dissipated in the sample is the kinetic energy of the piston system at the time of impact, minus what is absorbed by the foam pad. You should first measure how much is absorbed by the foam pad, a simple way is to tune your piston system so as to achieve the same deformation of the foam pad with no sample on the top.

This energy is the total energy that the sample has to dissipate, but the dynamics will very likely also play a role, a rate of energy dissipation is probably relevant.